# How do I tell Sphinx to Use the Anaconda Interpreter

Tags: python, anaconda, python-sphinx

I have created a Python project that uses Anaconda as the python interpreter. The project runs fine, but now I am attempting to use Sphinx to document it and I am running into an issue where it can't find the Crypto library. Is there a way to tell Sphinx to use the Anaconda Python Interpreter? Or a way to list the dependencies so that they can all be found?

Here is the error I get when I run the `make html` command:

```
Running Sphinx v1.5.5
making output directory...
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 6 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 6 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] modules

C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\docs\source\http.rst:19: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'h
ttp.security_mgr'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 551, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\http\security_mgr.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] modules
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in build\html.
```

Here is my make file:

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd %~dp0

REM Command file for Sphinx documentation

if "%SPHINXBUILD%" == "" (
    set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
)
set SOURCEDIR=source
set BUILDDIR=build
set SPHINXPROJ=PythonSDK

if "%1" == "" goto help

%SPHINXBUILD% >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 9009 (
    echo.
    echo.The 'sphinx-build' command was not found. Make sure you have Sphinx
    echo.installed, then set the SPHINXBUILD environment variable to point
    echo.to the full path of the 'sphinx-build' executable. Alternatively you
    echo.may add the Sphinx directory to PATH.
    echo.
    echo.If you don't have Sphinx installed, grab it from
    echo.http://sphinx-doc.org/
    exit /b 1
)

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS%
goto end

:help
%SPHINXBUILD% -M help %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS%

:end
popd
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda's handling of virtual environments and packaging. For Python virtual environments where I install all my project's packages and Sphinx, I do not activate the virtual environment and I invoke Sphinx with `make html SPHINXBUILD=/path/to/virtual_environment/bin/sphinx-build`, and the docs build successfully. Perhaps Anaconda has something analogous?

Comment: @StevePiercy I’m not sure if I am pointing to the correct location. I located the Anaconda version of the path in the error and tried using the commands `make html SPHINXBUILD=C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\sphinx` and `make html SPHINXBUILD=C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\sphinx\ext` but I still get an error that it is using Python27 instead of Anaconda. Does your sphinx-build folder contain scripts like autodoc.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to remove all references to Python27 from the Path variable, remove the PYTHONHOME environment variable, and then use the command `make html SPHINXBUILD=C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\sphinx`